# Launch Ubuntu instead of going straight to BIOS

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, bios

I (sort of accidentally) deleted my windows partition with gparted when on Ubuntu, and now I can't do anything as when I restart I go straight to the Bios. 
My windows was on Disk0 (was about 500gb) and my Ubuntu was on Disk1(about 25gb)

Does anyone have an idea on what's going on? Have I made a big mistake and if so what steps should I now be taking?

I have a 128gb USB key which I backed my things on(so can't lose contsnt), and a 8gb USB key that I can use to help.

Any tips greatly appreciated, as as of now I'm stuck with my phone and a computer that can't get past bios

Comment: Both of these downvotes are frankly incomprehensible. +1 for the question and for the answer from me.

Comment: If it's an anywhere near modern computer you *probably* deleted the EFI boot partition, and now it's going straight to EFI (not BIOS). I know how to repair this from Windows, but never done it from Linux. Should be simple with a quick google though - `Restore EFI partition Linux` or something

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps from Official Ubuntu community help page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Basically you should write your usb stick with ubuntu and run it as live cd. Then from a terminal run:

```
 sudo grub-install /dev/sda2
```

If ubuntu appears installed on /dev/sda2.

For recovering files from Windows partition, you can use gddrescue.

```
sudo apt-get install gddrescue
sudo ddrescue /dev/sda1 /dev/sda3
```

Where sda3 would be a new partition with the size at least equal with the one from Windows.

Of course there are other tools out there:
https://www.linux.com/learn/get-your-data-back-linux-based-data-recovery-tools

Good luck!